# Optimize HTTPS connection in Java client

Tags: java, https

I'm trying to communicate with a RESTful API over SSL. The whole client application relies on a basic connection method which looks something like this

```
URL url = null;
       HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
       InputStream is = null;

       try {
                url = new URL(TARGET_URL);

                HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
                     public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                       return true;
                     }
                };

                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.setRequestMethod(requestType);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

                is = connection.getInputStream();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                StringBuffer lines = new StringBuffer();

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    lines.append(line).append(LINE_BREAKER);
                }
                return lines.toString();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Exception is :"+e.toString());
           return e.toString();
       }
     }
```

This works well, but is there a more efficient way? We've tried Apache HTTPClient. It has an awesomely simple API but when we compared the performance of the above code vs Apache HTTPClient with YourKit, the latter one was creating more objects than the first. How do I optimize this?

Comment: This sounds interesting, but you haven't mentioned if you are having a specific problem.  Is the number of objects generated via HTTPClient causing actual performance issues?  Or are you [pre-optimizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)?

Comment: The actual problem is too many number of objects being generated. This increases the memory taken by the Server and hence in turn, if the memory reaches MAX_HEAP_SPACE, then makes the GC active which in turn also increases CPU utilization after sometime. So if we can reduce the number of objects generated, it would cool down the CPU, or rather help the server to keep cool :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used HTTPClient (but not for HTTPS) but I think this applies to your case. The recommendation is to create a single HTTPClient for your server, and a new HTTPGet object per call. You'll want to specify the multi-threaded client connection manager with an appropriate number of connections to allocate per host, and max total connections when you initialize your HTTPClient.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds promising! Our only concern was whether we can safely share the connection object. But as you said, its the HTTPGet object that we need to instantiate per call. Will try and get back soon :)

Comment: The HTTPClient object is freely shareable between threads, but the individual methods are not.

Comment: Using static `HttpClient` initialized with a `PoolingClientConnectionManager` and a new `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` per call helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use `HttpCore` instead of `HttpClient`. `HttpCore` is a set of HTTP transport components `HttpClient` is based upon. It has been specifically optimized for low memory footprint as well as performance. It lacks higher level HTTP functionality provided by `HttpClient` (connection management, cookie & state management, authentication) but should be quite efficient in terms of memory utilization.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html

Comment: Kevin wrote above for HTTPClient "The recommendation is to create a single HTTPClient for your server, and a new HTTPGet object per call." How could something similar be achieved for HttpCore with HTTPS?